# Pick random from Java List []

Tags: java, arrays, list, random

I have a list of 14 items that I use in method. I was wondering how I can make randomly pick different items from the list instead of forcing selecting by list number [0] etc. The code in the method is like this.

```
stats.list[0].clone ();
```

I need to it be something like..

```
stats.list[RANDOMNUMBER/DECISION].clone ();
```

My list code is like

```
 list [0]  = new Ped (names.getString("idc"), "C");
 list [1]  = new Ped (names.getString("id"), "D");
```

Thanks for ya help!

Comment: err, lookup random in java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: yeh I did, just not sure how to implement it. Isn't this why stackoverflow is made for? Specific programming problems :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomNum = r.nextInt(sizeOfList);
stats.list[randomNum].clone ();
```

Use the random class.